# How do you align text so it is in the middle of a button in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Here is the current code I am using:

```
<UserControl
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="ButtonPrototype.MainPage"
    Width="640" Height="480">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="CellBorderBrush" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ContentPresenter
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"  
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CellTemplate}"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="80"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Button Content="A" Style="{StaticResource CellStyle}"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The Horizontal aligning works but the verticalalignment doesn't do anything. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that by assigning string to the `Content` of the the `ContentPresenter` Silverlight needs to create a form of `TextBlock` to present the string.  Its the position of this `TextBlock` which isn't centered in the vertical space provided by the `ContentPresenter`.  Modifying the button like this:-

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource CellStyle}">
   <TextBlock Text="A" VertialAlignment="Center" />
</Button>
```

would fix it.  However you might just want to be able to specifiy a simple string Content and have it centered.  In that case you could modify your template:-

```
<Border x:Name="CellBorderBrush" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center"HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

By placing the `ContentPresenter` in a `StackPanel` the `ContentPresenter` will take the minumum height needed to display its content.  The `StackPanel` in turn only has the height of its content and then it is centered within the `Border`.

If I were building this, this is what it would look like:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.Test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <Border x:Name="CellBorderBrush"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                <ContentPresenter
                      x:Name="contentPresenter"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style x:Key="CellStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource CellTemplate}" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="80" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource CellStyle}">
            <TextBlock Text="A" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is a more general approach to the button.  Of course its fine to use the simpler more perscriptive templates when the style is being used for a very specific local purposes.

Answer (score 8):

What I am using might help you in your cause:

```
<Button Content="A" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```